# IE 7 can't bind event (using .live()) to dynamically created element using .load()

Tags: jquery, load, live

I'm having trouble getting IE7 to keep a click event bound to an element that is added to the DOM using .load(). Here's some code:

```
$('.mybtn').live('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#mypage').load('load-this-page.htm');
});
```

And here's the html

```
<div id="mypage">
   <a href="#" class="mybtn">clickme</a>
   // stuff goes here
</div>
```

On page load the click works but once the div is loaded via the clickme link the click stops working in IE7. The clickme link is within the div on load and also within the load() loaded html file that's why I'm using live().

This code works in FF 3.6, fyi.

Anyone have any idea what's up (besides the fact the IE sucks balls)? Thanks!

EDIT: here's what loads into the div

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="02-01-2010" id="prev-month" class="mybtn"></a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <h3>March 2010</h3>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="04-01-2010" id="next-month" class="mybtn"></a>
    </li>
</ul>

<a href="#">link 1</a>
<a href="#">link 2</a>
<a href="#">link 3</a>
<a href="#">link 4</a>
```

Comment: What exactly is in the response to the "load()" call?  Is it an HTML fragment that includes the `<a>` tag, or is it a complete page (that is, a page starting with `<html>` etc)?

Comment: Pointy -Thanks! It's just a small bit of html that includes ul,li and some links-including this link <a href="#" class="mybtn">clickme</a>

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('#mypage').load('load-this-page.htm #DivOrWrapper');
```

Comment: Simeon - Thanks, but isn't your suggestion for loading only a portion of a page? The file that's getting loaded into the div has only a few ul, li and some links-including one to reload this div-Make sense?

Comment: Yes, I suggested this in case you were loading a complete HTML file, then this would solve the problem. But if that's not the case, then might I also see the code for the page you are loading?

Comment: You can try wrapping your content in a div or replacing *#DivOrWrapper* above with *body*

Answer (score 0):

From the [API documentation](http://api.jquery.com/load/), the page you're loading ("load-this-page.htm") cannot be a full HTML document, i.e. it can't have `<html>`, `<title>` or `<head>` elements, otherwise cross-browser compatibility isn't guaranteed.

Comment: Peter-thanks for the response. No it's not a full html doc. It's a small snippet of code with nothing but some ul and li and some links. One of the links should reload this small file back into the div

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is due to IE browser restrictions. Here's a quote from the jQuery Docs:

*Due to browser security restrictions, most "Ajax" requests are subject to the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy); the request can not successfully retrieve data from a different domain, subdomain, or protocol.*

This means that you can't do $load:

- From https://mydomain.com to http://mydomain.com
- From http://mydomain.com to http://www.mydomain.com
- From http://mydomain.com to http://mydomain.se

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
var fn = function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();
    $('#mypage')
        .load('load-this-page.htm')
        .find('.mybtn')
        .click(fn);
};

$('.mybtn').live('click', fn);
```